# Does Ubuntu need a FQDN to get internet and email working?

Tags: 14.04, networking, email, dynamic-ip

I want to replace Win XP on a computer with Ubuntu. Do I have to buy a domain name to get email to send/receive and get internet working? Because on my Ubuntu 14.04 at work, I had to buy a domain name to get a Mail Transfer Agent to receive and send email. I"m not sure if an email client (not the same as an MTA) has the same requirements.

(At work I got around this with a Perl program which talks directly to the SMTP server, because I only needed to send emails. On my old Win XP PC I need to run a regular email client to send and receive emails.)

Also, is it possible to use a dynamic IP with Ubuntu with an ISP like Comcast? If so, how would I set it up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Standard advice for dynamic IP hosts is to use external email accounts
[e.g. free email account(s) at gmail.com].

You may configure your MTA to **send** messages using one of such accounts.
You may configure fetchmail to retrieve messages from external mailbox to local mailboxes.